# VSCode: restore user settings after sync merge blunder

Tags: visual-studio-code

So I am setting up another machine and I installed VSCode and did sync my old account... it showed some merge conflict between the two... I just clicked resolve... and then it happened... all my settings are gone... and I am left with empty settings.json file (well, with one setting in about the icons).... how can I restore my previous version?

obviously myt original PC was automatically changed to no settings :'(

Comment: pretty much! promise I did a search before how could I do it... but looks like I was not searching correctly. Thanks

Comment: you're welcome. please close your question as a duplicate then :)

Answer (score 0):

Oh, thank God I found the solution...

so in the users AppData folder there is a sync/settings folder
(C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\sync\settings)

just found the encoded json file with my old settings...
asked chatGPT to decode it... and done... restored!

hope it helps someone